# CKEditor is not getting reloaded on react state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor

I am trying to create a react component which internally uses ckeditor. But CKEditor component is not getting reloaded/re-rendered, can somebody please help.

```
const CkEditor = ({value, onChange, className = {}}) => {


return (
    <div className={className}>
        <CKEditor
            initData={value} onChange={onChange}
        />
    </div>
)}
```

initData always remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

We were able to resolve the issue in the following way.

```
const CkEditor = ({
value, 
className = {}}) => {
const [editor, setEditor] = useState(null);

const onBeforeLoad = (e) => {
    setEditor(e.editor);
}

useEffect(() => {
    if (editor) {
        editor.setData(value);
    }
}, [value]);

return (
    <div className={className}>
        <CKEditor
            initData={value}
            onLoaded={onBeforeLoad}
        />
    </div>
);}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).